# Is there a way to find ids of two separate collections in one js function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have two collections in one database – "Neighborhood" and Restaurants". 
I am trying to find the id of the neighborhood that I am currently in so that my "back" button on the restaurant.ejs page takes me back to the page with the path that contains that neighborhood's id.

I've tried: 
findById({} ...
findById(id, ....
but I keep getting errors.

Here is my code – thinking I just need to add something in the ??? to fix:

```
neighborhood.get('restaurant/:id', (req, res) => {
  Restaurant.findById(req.params.id, (err, restaurantInfo) => {
    Neighborhood.findById(???, (err, foundNeighborhood) => {
      res.render('restaurant.ejs', {
        restaurant: restaurantInfo,
        neighborhood: foundNeighborhood
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: does the restaurantInfo contains any realation with the "Neighborhood" you are trying to find? eg: neighborhood_id

Comment: restaurantInfo has the neighborhood's name, amongst other info in the object, but not its id

Comment: then either make the neighborhood's name unique and find it by name or create a db relation with the Restaurant so you'll be able to find the neighborhood by id.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, either the `restaurantInfo` being returned will have some information about the neighborhood, as @paolo metioned above, or you would have to provide some way to look up the neighborhood in the `req`, maybe like this:

```
 Restaurant.findById(req.params.id, (err, restaurantInfo) => {
    Neighborhood.findById(req.params.neignborhoodId, (err, foundNeighborhood) => {
      res.render('restaurant.ejs', {
        restaurant: restaurantInfo,
        neighborhood: foundNeighborhood
      })
    })
  })
});
```

If you're getting errors, it would be good to check for errors in the callback like this:

```
 Restaurant.findById(req.params.id, (err, restaurantInfo) => {
   if (err) {
     return err  // you can add an error message here, too
   } else {
    Neighborhood.findById(req.params.neignborhoodId, (err, foundNeighborhood) => {
      if (err) {
        return err
      }
      res.render('restaurant.ejs', {
        restaurant: restaurantInfo,
        neighborhood: foundNeighborhood
        }
      })
    })
  })
});
```

I think the easiest, depending on your project, would be to include the neighborhood id as part of the restaurant info, then you could pass in the neighborhood id like this:
`Neighborhood.findById(restaurantInfo.neighborhoodId, (err, foundNeighborhood) => {`

If possible, you could use the neighborhood name to find the neighborhood id, since you said the restaurantInfo contains the neighborhood name.  Or you could use a Neighborhood.findByName search instead of a findById.

Comment: thanks, Brian. how would I go about adding the neighborhood id to the restaurant data without hard coding?

Comment: Not sure you can.  You'd probably need to add a row to the Neighborhood database to do this.  It might be easiest to write a new lookup function so that you look up the neighborhood by name.  As long as the neighborhood names are unique, that wouldn't be very hard to do.  If they aren't unique, like if you have every neighborhood in an entire country or something, you'll have to make some changes to the database structure.